# What does Bourbon's `transition()` mixin compile to in CSS?

Tags: css, sass, bourbon

In this YouTube [video](https://youtu.be/d4P8s-mkMvs?t=20m49s) @20:49, he uses is `transition()` in his stylesheet to enable the easing in and out of the off screen navigation. He is using `Bourbon` as well. How can I translate the same `transition` effect into regular CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the source for that mixin [here.](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/v4-stable/app/assets/stylesheets/css3/_transition.scss) If you don't pass any args, the default settings use 0.15s and compile to:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
-moz-transition:all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
transition:all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
```